# Spring boot config client properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot-configuration

```
//This is the value of the property which needs to be fetched via config server from git repo
ConfigClientController(@Value("**${foo:test}"**) String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

The above code is a spring cloud config client(spring.application.name=foo) that gets the config properties from the git config repo.
Foo is the property in foo.properties. Here I am little confused about the :test param in the code above. I wanted to know what is the significance of this param in getting the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `foo` parameter is not present meaning it cannot be obtained from the config `test` string will be used instead. Meaning - what's after the `:` is a default value for the `@Value` annotated param.